# How to solve an unexpected token that Jest encountered

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, babeljs

I've created a custom library and added to a project.

My problem is that now, doesnt pass my tests... before add my custom library passed all tests.

But now show me next error:

```
 Jest encountered an unexpected token

    This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

    By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

    Here's what you can do:
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

    Details:

    C:\Users\francabre\Documents\gitprojects\demo\node_modules\react-dnd\dist\esm\index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './common';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/frontend-collective-react-dnd-scrollzone/lib/index.js:24:17)
```

I'm searching info and I've tried things that people said, but I can solve it.

I use this command to pass my test: `"test": "npm-run-all --parallel lint test:no-cli"`

Any idea??

Thanks for read me and try to help me

Edit:

I've solved changing react-dnd by react-dnd-cjs

Comment: The error points to "export * from './common'". I'd search all files for that exact text.